# Convert Blu-Ray to MP4

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, plex

I have been playing for about 2 weeks now on `handbrake` trying to convert my `Panasonic handycam videos` which are in `m2ts` format to `mp4`.

Here is the orignal file details:

```
General
ID                                       : 0 (0x0)
Complete name                            : E:\Panasonic\house 2017.m2ts
Format                                   : BDAV
Format/Info                              : Blu-ray Video
File size                                : 3.77 GiB
Duration                                 : 21 min 45 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 24.8 Mb/s
Maximum Overall bit rate                 : 28.0 Mb/s

Video
ID                                       : 4113 (0x1011)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.2
Format settings                          : CABAC / 2 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, RefFrames               : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : 27
Duration                                 : 21 min 44 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 23.6 Mb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 25.0 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 50.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.227
Stream size                              : 3.58 GiB (95%)

Audio
ID                                       : 4352 (0x1100)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Codec ID                                 : 129
Duration                                 : 21 min 44 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 256 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 31.250 FPS (1536 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 39.8 MiB (1%)
Service kind                             : Complete Main
```

My is question is how to change the following in `Handbrake`

```
Codec ID                                : mp42 (mp42,avc1)
Format profile                          : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 2 Ref Frames
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=6
Bit rate                                 : 14.0 Mb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 16.8 Mb/s
```

The closest I ever came to this is the following but it has horrible lag between audio/video and i video stutters when playing on plex app on my smart TV but video works fine on my laptop.

```
General
Complete name                            : E:\Media\cli plex 10000.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 1.57 GiB
Duration                                 : 21 min 44 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 10.3 Mb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-10-10 16:16:23
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-10-10 16:16:23
Writing application                      : HandBrake 1.0.7 2017100700

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L5
Format settings                          : CABAC / 8 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, RefFrames               : 8 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 21 min 44 s
Duration_LastFrame                       : 20 ms
Bit rate                                 : 10 000 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 50.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.096
Stream size                              : 1.51 GiB (96%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 148
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=8 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x133 / me=umh / subme=9 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=500 / keyint_min=50 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=60 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=10000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-10-10 16:16:23
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-10-10 16:16:23
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 21 min 44 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 160 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 24.9 MiB (2%)
Title                                    : Stereo / Stereo
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-10-10 16:16:23
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-10-10 16:16:23
Fallback From                            : 3

Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Codec ID                                 : ac-3
Duration                                 : 21 min 44 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 256 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 31.250 FPS (1536 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 39.8 MiB (2%)
Title                                    : Stereo / Stereo
Service kind                             : Complete Main
Default                                  : Inherited From: 2
Alternate group                          : 1
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-10-10 16:16:23
Tagged date                              : UTC 2017-10-10 16:16:23
Fallback To                              : 2
```

Comment: Does `ffmpeg -i input.m2ts -c copy -c:a aac output.mp4` work on your TV?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard yes, both the `m2ts` and `output.mp4` work on my Sony Bravia when I get `plex` to limit the bitrate at `8Megs` because it buffers to play these files at their original bitrate. However, these files sizes are massive (3.6GB) for just 21 min clip. This was the main reason to use `handbrake` to slash these sizes by more than 50% whilst retaining the video quality

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I just want to keep everything as is in the `output.mp4` but change the `bitrate` and `maximum bit rate`. Could you help with that please?

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i input.m2ts -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -t 10 -movflags +faststart output.mp4`